# Questions about creating context memory surges

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, layer, uigraphicscontext

- **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions** function's size parameter is too large, resulting in memory surge.
- I use size data, which is    about 3 times the height and width of
  the screen size, which is
  **(3*UIScreen.main.bounds.height,3*UIScreen.main.bounds.width)**. But when generating the image context, it produces huge memory, which is 
  definitely not working.
- How to generate a smaller image context    memory, I think about a
  way to solve, is to generate a local(partial) context,    but I feel this will
  produce too many steps.
- I hope that a friend can    discuss this issue with me and propose a
  better solution

Comment: Divide **UIScreen.main.bouns.height** and **UIScreen.main.bouns. weught** by two

Comment: @A.Munzer,it's a spelling mistake，`let size = (3*UIScreen.main.bounds.height,3*UIScreen.main.bounds.width)`

Comment: Because the screen size certainly cannot display the entire context of the layer, when the screen is displayed in a certain area of the full context, a local context is created to draw the image data of this area, which can reduce the memory, but this is a bit too much trouble, I hope A friend can propose a solution to the memory compression of the image context